# C# call same extended function with different type as parameter (maybe delegates ?)

Tags: c#, generics, interface, delegates, extends

I'm trying to build a rule-checker for my project that cycle through a list of rules and return me if any of those have the flag true.
Below a code i wrote as sample of what i'm trying to do (not the actual code, please ignore eventually not observed best practices or niceties).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface ICounterValued {
    int CounterValue {get;}
    int CounterLimit {get;}
}

public interface ITimeValued {
    float ElapsedTime {get;}
    float TimeLimit {get;}
}

public class MyMainClass : ICounterValued , ITimeValued {
    // Counter data
    private int     _counterValue   = 0;
    private int     _counterLimit   = 10;
    // Time data
    private float   _elapsedTime    = 0;
    private float   _timeLimit      = 10f;
    // ICounterValued
    public int      CounterValue    => _counterValue;
    public int      CounterLimit    => _counterLimit;
    // ITimeValued
    public float    ElapsedTime     => _elapsedTime;
    public float    TimeLimit       => _timeLimit;

    public RuleChecker  ruleChecker;

    public void InitializeMe(){
        ruleChecker = new RuleChecker();
        ruleChecker.rules.Add( new TimeRule() );
        ruleChecker.rules.Add( new CounterRule() );
    }

    public void UpdateRuleChecker(){
        ruleChecker.CheckRules<MyMainClass>( this );
    }

    public bool NeedToStop(){
        return ruleChecker.SomeRuleTriggered();
    }
}

public class RuleChecker {
    public List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>();

    public void CheckRules<T>( T data ){
        rules.ForEach( x => x.UpdateMe<T>(data) );
    }

    public bool SomeRuleTriggered(){
        return rules.Any( x => x.IsTriggered() );
    }
}

public abstract class Rule {
    protected bool _triggered;

    public virtual bool IsTriggered() =>  _triggered;
    // check logic that will set the _triggered flag to true
    public abstract void UpdateMe<T>( T data );
}

public class TimeRule : Rule {
    public override void UpdateMe<ITimeValued>( ITimeValued data ){
        _triggered = (data.ElapsedTime >= data.TimeLimit);
    }
}

public class CounterRule : Rule {
    public override void UpdateMe<ICounterValued>( ICounterValued data ){
        _triggered = (data.CounterValue >= data.CounterLimit);
    }
}
```

The point of that is to use the same rule-checker in future for different "MainClasses" that have one or more interfaces and the possibility to reuse that rules or add new ones like "modules" with his own triggering logic.

The code above doesn't work because when i call the generic voids (`UpdateMe<ICounterValued>` and `UpdateMe<ITimeValued>`) data value cannot access the attributes i defined inside the interfaces (`CounterValue`,`CounterLimit`,`ElapsedTime`,`TimeLimit`).

I'm assuming that there are some conversion or interface problem to this void generics approach; Is not necessary for me to use generics but i didn't find a more clever solution to this; I've tryied something with delegates as parameter of `UpdateMe` in `Rule` class but nothing that can be extended with different type parameter and let the rule-checker call all in one by passing the instance of `MyMainClass` for each one.

Thanks in andavace for any suggestions.

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting and where exactly is the error?

Comment: I think, but I'm not sure that the problem is that you don't have a constraint on `T` in `Rule.UpdateMe<T>` that allows accessing the properites.  I thought I could get away with creating a base interface `public interface IValued { int Value { get; } int Limit { get; } }` and then explicitly implementing the `ICounterValued` and `ITimeValued` (and ignoring int/float for now).  I can't find the magic sauce so far.  I hope this rambling helps

Comment: @Flydog57 The error is `'ITimeValued' does not contain a definition for 'ElapsedTime' and no accessible extension method 'ElapsedTime' accepting a first argument of type 'ITimeValued' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`, the same for all the other properties.
Your solution can be done if i always know what type of data will be inside the interface.
A real usage of what i'm trying to achieve, for example is to use more complex interfaces like this: 
```
public interface ITimer {
        AdvancedTimer Timer { get; }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I copied your code and tried to get it to compile, got the same error.  It's because of the missing constraint on `T`.  You can't call something on a `T` unless `T` is constrained in a way that allows the call to happen.  It's too late for me to think right now, but your question has me intrigued.  I may come up with a solution once I step away.

Comment: @Flydog57 I think you are right, the override of `UpdateMe` make the `data` attribute treated as a generic `T` value and not with the overridden interface type. Generics solutions looks too limited to do something so inhomogeneous; Maybe something with delegates that return a `bool` can be doable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution that seems to work and is close to what I was searcing for.
The first solution of @Caius Jard worked too but I think that it would be better to avoid keep pointing the checking instance inside a variable of a rule.
Below the same sample code in my question but with comments next to the updated code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public interface ICounterValued {
    int CounterValue {get;}
    int CounterLimit {get;}
}

public interface ITimeValued {
    float ElapsedTime {get;}
    float TimeLimit {get;}
}

public class MyMainClass : ICounterValued , ITimeValued {
    // Counter data
    private int     _counterValue   = 0;
    private int     _counterLimit   = 10;
    // Time data
    private float   _elapsedTime    = 0;
    private float   _timeLimit      = 10f;
    // ICounterValued
    public int      CounterValue    => _counterValue;
    public int      CounterLimit    => _counterLimit;
    // ITimeValued
    public float    ElapsedTime     => _elapsedTime;
    public float    TimeLimit       => _timeLimit;

    public RuleChecker  ruleChecker;

    public void InitializeMe(){
        ruleChecker = new RuleChecker();
        ruleChecker.rules.Add( new TimeRule() );
        ruleChecker.rules.Add( new CounterRule() );
    }

    // I don't need this anymore, the condition will be checked
    // inside SomeRuleTriggered
    // public void UpdateRuleChecker(){
    //     ruleChecker.CheckRules<MyMainClass>( this );
    // }

    public bool NeedToStop(){
        // The instance will be passed as argument
        // return ruleChecker.SomeRuleTriggered();
        return ruleChecker.SomeRuleTriggered( this );
    }
}

public class RuleChecker {
    public List<Rule> rules = new List<Rule>();

    // As commented above, I don't need to update a stored 
    // flag in Rule (and direved) anymore
    // public void CheckRules<T>( T data ){
    //     rules.ForEach( x => x.UpdateMe<T>(data) );
    // }

    // Now the instance will be passed as a generic object and parsed
    // inside IsTriggered method
    // public bool SomeRuleTriggered(){
    //     return rules.Any( x => x.IsTriggered() );
    // }
    public bool SomeRuleTriggered( object target ){
        return rules.Any( x => x.IsTriggered( target ) );
    }
}

public abstract class Rule {
    // No need to update a falg anymore
    // protected bool _triggered;

    // No need to update a falg anymore
    // public virtual bool IsTriggered() =>  _triggered;

    // No need to update a falg anymore
    // public abstract void UpdateMe<T>( T data );
    public abstract bool IsTriggered( object target );
}

public class TimeRule : Rule {
    // No need to update a falg anymore
    // public override void UpdateMe<ITimeValued>( ITimeValued data ){
    //     _triggered = (data.ElapsedTime >= data.TimeLimit);
    // }
    public override bool IsTriggered( object target ){
        ITimeValued target_timed = target as ITimeValued;
        if( null == target_timed)
            return false;

        return (target_timed.ElapsedTime >= target_timed.TimeLimit);
    }
}

public class CounterRule : Rule {
    // No need to update a falg anymore
    // public override void UpdateMe<ICounterValued>( ICounterValued data ){
    //     _triggered = (data.CounterValue >= data.CounterLimit);
    // }
    public override bool IsTriggered( object target ){
        ICounterValued target_counter = target as ICounterValued;
        if( null == target_counter)
            return false;

        return (target_counter.CounterValue >= target_counter.CounterLimit);
    }
}
```

As you can see the `RuleChecker` can call the method on any `Rule` derived class passing the checking instance as a generic `object`. Any class that extends `Rule` can implement his rule-logic overriding `IsTriggered` with an explicit cast inside, and then finally start checking.

Answer (score 2):

Structuring (your approach) this way makes more sense to me:

```
public class RuledClass{
    public List<Rule> Rules = new List<Rule>();
    
    public bool AnyViolated(){
        return Rules.Any(r => r.IsViolated());
    }
}

public class MyMainClass : RuledClass, ICounterValued , ITimeValued {
    // Counter data
    public int     CounterValue {get;set;} 
    public int    CounterLimit  {get;set;} 
    // Time data
    public float  ElapsedTime   {get;set;} 
    public float  TimeLimit   {get;set;}   
    // ICounterValued
    

    public MyMainClass(){
        Rules.Add( new TimeRule(this) );
        Rules.Add( new CounterRule(this) );
    }
}

public abstract class Rule {
    public abstract bool IsViolated();
}

public class TimeRule : Rule {
    private ITimeValued _thing;
    public TimeRule(ITimeValued thing){
        _thing = thing;
    }
    public override bool IsViolated(){
        return (_thing.ElapsedTime >= _thing.TimeLimit);
    }
}
public class CounterRule : Rule {
    private ICounterValued _thing;
    public CounterRule(ICounterValued thing){
        _thing = thing;
    }
    public override bool IsViolated(){
        return (_thing.CounterValue >= _thing.CounterLimit);
    }
}
```

I couldn't work out, with your approach, why class X would have a list of rules that one could potentially pass a class Y to; the rules and the class they apply to are tied together in my mind.. as such I make that link at construction time

..But even then I don't know if I'd do it this way

I think I'd more likely do something like:

```
public class RuledClass{
    public List<Func<bool>> Rules = new List<Func<bool>>();
    
    public bool AnyViolated(){
        return Rules.Any(r => r());
    }
}

public class MyMainClass : RuledClass {
    // Counter data
    public int     CounterValue {get;set;} 
    public int    CounterLimit  {get;set;} 
    // Time data
    public float  ElapsedTime   {get;set;} 
    public float  TimeLimit   {get;set;}   
    // ICounterValued
    

    public MyMainClass(){
        Rules.Add(()=>ElapsedTime>TimeLimit);
        Rules.Add(()=>CounterValue>CounterLimit);
    }
}
```

Comment: The first code is the closest, i just tryied the solution in my code and with some adjustment i can make it work sending the instance inside the constructor of the rule and storing the MyMainClass instance as interface like you wrote: `private ICounterValued _thing;`.
extending RuledClass is not a good idea because MyMainClass usually need to extend another base class that is not Ruled.
The second solution is too oriented on my sample code, there i must need to write the "Violation Logic" in every class that need a TimeLimit Rule or Counter Rule for example.

Comment: I only made a RuledClass because I didn't want to provide a rules prop definition every time; you can make it an interface if you're happy to repeat rules definition everywhere that is IRuleable. *The second solution is too oriented on my sample code* - such is the consequence of providing contrived examples I'm afraid.. *there i must need to write the "Violation Logic"* - but by making it an interface you then have to "write more properties in every class that need a X for example".. The logic of the second is very simple, and really allows a class to set its own crazy varied rules..

Comment: ..without an endless proliferation of interfaces, and implementations of them, and instances that support them.. As presented it makes a class responsible for checking that it is valid, but i think there's no reason an external class couldn't give the set of rule `Func`s that live in the array